# Paypal Personal Payments with Preapproval

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

Here's the user story I am dealing with:

A user wants to send a personal payment to a friend to reimburse him for money. 
The user adds the friends email and the amount. 
We check if the recipient is a paypal user by making a call to the Adaptive Payments API PAY method. 
The recipient is not a paypal user. 
Then we make a preapproval for the funds transfer for the sender. 
Later when we have the correct paypal address for the recipient we try and make the payment using the PERSONAL payment type and including the Preapproval token. 
The API returns this error: "Personal payment type is not allowed for this payment"

Is there something I'm missing here or are preapprovals for personal payments just not possible with paypal?

Answer (score 0):

Personal payments require a special permission on your account. You need to submit an application on x.com and request it.